# Can #if conditional areas cross include file boundaries?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

In the MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx) I see the following:

> All conditional-compilation directives, such as #if and #ifdef, must
>   be matched with closing #endif directives prior to the end of file;
>   otherwise, an error message is generated. When conditional-compilation
>   directives are contained in include files, they must satisfy the same
>   conditions: There must be no unmatched conditional-compilation
>   directives at the end of the include file.

Well, simple and clear. A the same time I cannot find something like that in the C++11 standard. My question is this legal limitation?

I fully understand that splitting conditional compilation over several `#include`  layers is not a good idea and should be avoided.

Does anybody know how other compilers (GCC, CLANG) handle this case? Maybe this was discussed somewhere?

Comment: You apparently ask about the C++ standard, so don't add C tag.

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you do this?

Comment: Well, this is relevant for C also. It has different standard that may say something different.

Comment: @Alex: VisualStudio gives `fatal error C1004:`

Comment: The only indication for this I could find at a quick glance is that the top-most non-terminal in the grammar describing the preprocessing directives in the standard is named *preprocessing-file* [cpp]. So it seems the intention is that the constructs may not span multiple files.

Comment: I assume there's some Boost library that relies on this not being a limitation...

Comment: @Barry: In which case it doesn't compile with either of gcc or clang, nor, from what the OP says, MS compilers. Which is rather a severe restriction.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I was joking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#if FOO
#include "hashif.h"


extern "C" int printf(const char* fmt, ...);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
}
```

and `hashif.h` contains this:

```
#define BAR 1
#else
#define BAR 2
#endif
```

then clang++ gives an error.

```
hashif.cpp:1:2: error: unterminated conditional directive
#if FOO  
^
1 error generated.
```

Edit: And `g++` and `cpp` all behave the same way.

Exact output from:

```
$ cpp hashif.cpp -DFOO=1
# 1 "hashif.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "hashif.cpp"

# 1 "hashif.h" 1
In file included from hashif.cpp:2:0:
hashif.h:2:2: error: #else without #if
 #else
  ^
hashif.h:3:0: warning: "BAR" redefined
 #define BAR 2
 ^
hashif.h:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define BAR 1
 ^
hashif.h:4:2: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
  ^
# 3 "hashif.cpp" 2


extern "C" int printf(const char* fmt, ...);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
hashif.cpp:1:0: error: unterminated #if
 #if FOO
 ^
}
```

Comment: did you define FOO? else it wouldn't include your header

Comment: @Anedar: Does not matter, (but it does give some other errors for the `#else` and `#endif` if `FOO` is defined)

Comment: It would be nice to add these errors to your answer.

Comment: @KirillKobelev: Added full logs of running `cpp` - since it goes wrong early on the compilation phase, the output from the "proper" compilers is pretty much the same except it doesn't list the source content.

Comment: Yes, I see. These errors clearly indicate what compiler thinks about what is going on.